# Grep a time stamp in the H:MM:SS format

Tags: bash, grep

Working on the file an need to grep the line with a time stamp in the `H:MM:SS` format. I tried the following egrep `'[0-9]\:[0-9]\:[0-9]'`. Didn't work for me. What am i doing wrong in regex?

Comment: What's going to happen if your timestamp is 1:30:30?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fix:

```
grep '[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]'
```

If you need get timestamp only, and your grep is gnu grep.

```
grep -o '[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]'
```

and if you work more harder, limit on time format only:

```
grep '[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ date -u | egrep '\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}'
Fri May  2 00:59:47 UTC 2014
```

Try a site like http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way that I know of:

```
grep -E '([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}' file
```

If you need month and day also:

```
grep -E '.{3,4} .{,2} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}' file
```